# MYSQL - Display list of names where ID appears more than once in a column

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anyone point out what is wrong with the following code please

---EDITED WITH CORRECT ANSWER---

```
SELECT hist.TutorID, FirstName, LastName, COUNT(hist.TutorID) as 
number_students
FROM match_history as hist
JOIN tutor ON tutor.TutorID 
WHERE hist.TutorID = tutor.TutorID
GROUP BY hist.TutorID
HAVING (number_students > 1)
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Add "group by" to your subquery and IN in where clause:

```
SELECT tut.TutorID, FirstName, LastName
FROM tutor AS tut
WHERE tutorid in (SELECT TutorID FROM match_history group by tutorid HAVING COUNT(TutorID) >1);
```

Hope that first name and lastname from Tutor table. Or provide your tables structure.

Comment: This returns an error  'Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row
'

Comment: @Rick D Please let us know whether your problem fixed by Setting Green flag and Voting for the Answer. Thanks.

Comment: this doesn't work, I'm trying to get the total repeat occurrences of an ID from the tutorID column

Comment: @RickD Tell me again your request please, we just make your script better, but now you wrote something different...
And also provide your tables data structure, and more clear example for your request.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tut.TutorID, FirstName, LastName
FROM tutor AS tut, match_history as hist
WHERE tut.TutorID in (SELECT TutorID FROM match_history GROUP BY TutorID HAVING COUNT(TutorID) > 1);
```

The inner select provides a list of TutorIDs that have a count > 1, the outer select grabs the id and other columns only from the list of ids provided by the inner select.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tut.TutorID, 
FirstName, 
LastName
FROM tutor AS tut
LEFT JOIN match_history hist ON (tut.TutorID = hist.TutorID)
GROUP BY tut.TutorID
HAVING COUNT(hist.TutorID) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

use `GROUP BY` Clause:

```
SELECT tut.TutorID, FirstName, LastNamecode 
FROM tutor AS tut, match_history as hist
WHERE tut.TutorID in (SELECT TutorID FROM match_history 
GROUP BY TutorID   
HAVING COUNT(TutorID) > 1);
```